# change value of h:outputtext using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsf

i have one component OutputText , i want to change its value using jquery,

my component is,

```
<h:outputText id="txt_pay_days"  value="0" 
    binding="#{Attendance_Calculation.txt_pay_days}"/>
```

thanks for any help...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<h:outputText>` will be converted to `<span>` in raw HTML So,

Use id of the DOM and play with jQuery

```
${"#txt_pay_days"}.text("New Value To Set");
```

Comment: Not necessary this will work: looks like that question is about asp .net, then id can be altered by compiller and resulting id can be something like ctl00_MainContent_SubmitButton

Comment: @VikciaR Question is about JSF, `<h:outputText>` is JSF's component

Comment: You're confusing `<h:outputText>` with `<h:inputText>`.

Comment: OP asked about `<h:outputText>`.

Comment: @BalusC I will still edit it but I think you have already answered it

Answer (score 4):

The `<h:outputText>` renders a HTML `<span>` with the value as its body.

```
<span id="txt_pay_days">0</span>
```

The [jQuery `.val()` function](http://api.jquery.com/val/) works on HTML **input** elements like `<input type="text">` only. The `<span>` isn't an input element at all. Instead, you need to use the [jQuery `.text()` function](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

```
$("#txt_pay_days").text("123");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
$('#txt_pay_days').val('valueYouWantToInsert');
```